# American Contingent Claim vs European Option pricing

Tags: finance-mathematics, european-options

Suppose $Y$ is an American Contingent Claim (ACC) defined as $Y = \{Y_t, t \in 0,1,...,T\}$ and asssume $U_t$ is its fair price. Also suppose $C_t$ is the arbitrage-free price at time $t$ of a European option with maturity $T$ and payoff $Y_T$.

i) Write the Doob decomposition of the discounted fair price $U_t := U_t(1 + r)^{-t}$ for $t \in \{0,1,...,T\}$ of the ACC.

ii) Show that $C_t \leq U_t$ for all $t$.

iii) Show that if $C_t \geq Y_t$ for all $t$, then $C_t = U_t$.

I have received the following partial solution. What about the other two points?

i) $V_t(\Phi) = \alpha_tS_t + \beta_tB_t + \frac{\delta_n}{B_{n-1}}$.
Then we have $\hat{V}_t(\Phi) = \hat{U}_t + \frac{\delta_n}{B_{n-1}}$.

Here we set $M_t := \hat{V}_t(\Phi)$ and $A_t := \frac{\delta_n}{B_{n-1}}$.

By the definition of $\delta_n$, we know it is a predictive process and it is non-decreasing, and $M_t$
is a martingale as $\Phi$ here is a self-financing strategy.

Comment: Sorry but I find your question difficult to read and thus to comprehend. A big part of that is due to the notation. Please invest some time in learning Mathjax for writing equations: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @Jennifer Tried to rewrite the formulas in your question with MathJax and improve your wording as it looks like your question might be closed soon. The changes should appear if and when approved. Feel free to modify the changes as per necessary. Can you pls also tell us where the question is originally from and where you got the partial solution to the first part from